# Как сделать в PostgreSQL фасетную выборку?

Tags: sql, postgresql, mongodb

Как сделать фасетную выборку в PosgreSQL по типу как в mongodb $facet?
Когда можно сделать несколько независимых друг от друга запросов одновременно и вывести их в один результат.

Comment: cte и to_json, json_build_object, json_agg, row_to_json и т.д. из https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Comment: если хочешь конкретики то покажи структуру, данные и задачу